# Counting number of occurrences in a column, and eliminating repeats based on another column

Tags: google-sheets, count, unique, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to take what's essentially a sign-in sheet for students being tutored, and then list, for each course, how many visits and how many different students visited seeking help. It seems kinda complicated to me so hopefully I can explain it well enough.

In `sheetA` I have data as follows:

```
 |     A      |    B    |  C  |  D  |    E    |
-+------------+---------+-----+-----+---------+
1|    Name    |  Date   | In  | Out | Course  |
-+------------+---------+-----+-----+---------+
2|    Ann     |##/##/## |  #  |  #  |  MA101  |
3|    Bob     |##/##/## |  #  |  #  |  MA101  |
4|    Jim     |##/##/## |  #  |  #  |  MA101  |
5|    Bob     |##/##/## |  #  |  #  |  MA101  |
6|    Ann     |##/##/## |  #  |  #  |  MA101  |
7|    Bob     |##/##/## |  #  |  #  |  MA101  |
8|    Ann     |##/##/## |  #  |  #  |  CS101  |
```

Then in `sheetB` the output would be:

```
 |     A     |   B   |   C   |
 +-----------+-------+-------+
1|   Course  | Total | Unique|
 +-----------+-------+-------+
2|   MA101   |   6   |   3   | #This would be 3 because only 3 unique students came
3|   CS101   |   1   |   1   |
```

So all courses are listed under `A`, the total visits for that course are in `B`, and `C` is the number of unique students that went for that course.

**What I have so far:**

In `sheetB` I have the formulas for `A` and `B`.

**A2:** `=unique(transpose(split(ArrayFormula(concatenate('sheetA'!E2:E&" "))," ")))`

**B2:** `=arrayformula(if(len(A7:A),countif(transpose(split(ArrayFormula(concatenate('sheetA'!E2:E&" "))," ")),A7:A),iferror(1/0)))`

If it helps to look at I put these equations broken up with comments for what I understand each part to do in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/joshgrib/f0e231ff94fef5dcd70f)

I'm trying to figure out what to put in `C2`, and I'm just totally lost.

Even if anyone knows a better way to do what I did so far, i.e. more concise or something, because those were from another SO post.

Comment: It would be much easier to do it with a google script, are you open to use something like that?

Comment: @Maljam Yeah absolutely, I just have very limited experience with them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YOu can do this easily with native formulas:

[image]

THe formulas are:

```
=UNIQUE(E3:E)

=COUNTIF(E3:E,F2)

=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(A3:A,E3:E=F2)))
```